# Linux Root Partition gets corrupted frequently

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, windows-10, data-corruption

I have Ubuntu 20.04 Installed Alongside Windows 10. Used it for more than a year and worked flawlessly but now I'm facing this disk corruption error.
First Encounter: Was Trying to take a screenshot but my system became read-only and I had to restart my pc, upon restart BusyBox Greeted me with this error:

```
/dev/sda4 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda4:
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda4: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
    (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda4 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I did not know what to do but then I googled it and used `fsck /dev/sda4` and it was Corrected and upon restart, everything was back to normal.
But then it kept repeating, I had to do fsck 2-3 times a day. Most of the time my pc would freeze and Display would just cutoff (Black screen and standby/no input) and then I had to restart which greets me with the same BusyBox Screen

I got frustrated and reinstalled Linux (Ubuntu) [Screwed up a bit, Mentioned at the end of the post]

But now even after reinstall it's not That Frequent but it's definitely not gone.
Along with Linux Windows Also Did Disk Repairs on every Boot but now, Windows won't boot (stuck on Microsoft logo) and even if it does after few minutes I get the Blue screen saying Critical System Process Failed/stoped followed by disk repair (Ubuntu Also reported me of critical System process Died and when I hit report it would say "System report has crashed/failed)
Sometimes the system would also say "not enough Memory to analyze the Error"

Observations:
Corruption Mostly Happened if,

1. Too many Chrome Tabs Open
2. Too many apps Opened at once (resulting pc freeze and then screen off)

I Have 4GB Ram And 6GB Swap Space.

During reinstallation, I also Moved my 500GB partition (Where I store all my files) To be before my Linux partition. So if it were physical damage to the drive, it would not have repeated (Guess)

```
Early Partition Order:
1. Windows 10           200GB
2. Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) 296GB
3. Linux Swap           6GB
4. Drive                500GB

Current Partition Order:
1. Windows 10           200GB
2. Drive                500GB
3. Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) 296GB
4. Linux Swap           6GB
```

I did this cause I read swap areas are faster if placed at the end to the start

Currently, My Pc is Running `sudo badblocks -vs /dev/sda > badsectors.txt` cause I want to make sure there's nothing wrong with my HDD, (10 Hours Elapsed, 41% Done)

(At First, I thought windows might be messing with the file system but the corruption also occurred between consecutive Linux Boot...)

> Once, I also lost my system Configurations, and the other time I lost my Chrome Configurations.

Please Suggest what I can do :(

Hardware:

- 1TB HDD
- Intel Core i3-4130 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4
- GeForce GT 610/PCIe/SSE2
- 4GB DDR3 RAM

> While reinstallation, I used UEFI Mode instead of non-UEFI which resulted in grub2 installation failure, I retried it several times and also Format Linux partition Hoping that it would remove grub along with Linux and I could clean install it but ofc it didn't work But then I realized And booted My Pendrive in non-UEFI Mode and Installation proceeded Properly and the system And Grub2 was properly installed

Ended up looking like a huge Story, idk how to explain in short...sorry for the trouble :\

Answer (score 2):

you might want to install SMART tools to see how close to absolute failure your hard-disc is.
But first - BACKUP to an attached USB or HD - if you run like me with machine on a lot of the time, don't reboot - copy all of /home and /etc ASAP
Victim of a sequential RAID failure - it's not pretty

Just in case - anything important to you copy NOW and buy a new harddisc.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard disk appears to be failing and needs replacing. This link will give you some additional details about hard disks symptoms when failing. https://www.prosofteng.com/blog/warning-signs-and-symptoms-of-hard-drive-failure

Comment: `sudo badblocks -vs /dev/sda > badsectors.txt` is 65% Done 20 Hours in, If somethings wrong with HDD, It would Detect right?
(I never kept my pc on for 20 hours continuously...it's making weird noises now but it seems to be from the Fan)

Comment: `Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)`

Could the problem still be with my HDD?

Comment: yes I have run many different kinds of tests on failing hard drives and they often pass till they do not.  All you have said here tells me its failing get the data if you can and replace..